# Bigquery time between 2 specific Google Analytics page hits

Tags: sql, google-analytics, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Newby here. I'm trying to find the average time taken by users on our site to get from one page (getting a quote) to another (applying). Using Google Analytics data in BigQuery. I'd like to split this by channel, but initially I'm just trying to get the times for each user.

I've tried inner and left join but both are returning table*table number of results. Both subqueries look correct when run separately (quotes returns 925, applications returns 117) but when joining them I'm getting duplicates.

The commented out bits are for the final query, and can be ignored, just including for context.

```
-- SELECT
--   channelGrouping,
--   ROUND(AVG(timeQ2A/60000),2) AS avgMinsQ2A
-- FROM (

   SELECT
    CONCAT(CAST(visitId AS STRING),'_',fullVisitorId) AS sessionId,
    apps.channelGrouping,
    (quote.quoteTime) as quoteTime,
    (CAST(hits.time AS INT64)) AS appTime,
    (CAST(hits.time AS INT64) - (quote.quoteTime)) AS timeQ2A
  FROM
    `project.dataset.ga_sessions_20190923` AS apps,
    UNNEST(hits) AS hits
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
     MIN(CAST(hits.time AS INT64)) AS quoteTime,
     CONCAT(CAST(visitId AS STRING),'_',fullVisitorId) AS sessionId     
    FROM
      `project.dataset.ga_sessions_20190923`,
      UNNEST(hits) AS hits
    WHERE
      hits.type = "PAGE"
      AND hits.page.pagePath = "/get-a-quote/"
      AND hits.time > 0 
    GROUP BY
    2) AS quote
  ON
    sessionId = quote.sessionId
  WHERE
    hits.type = "PAGE"
    AND hits.page.pagePath = "/application-complete/"
  GROUP BY
    1,
    2,3,4
ORDER BY 1,2,3
--     )
-- GROUP BY
--   1
-- ORDER BY 
--   2 DESC
```

I'd expect to only get 117 rows (all users who have applied will be in the quotes table so inner and left should be the same), but I'm getting 108k.

Any assistance much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I had to guess, I would say you have multiple hits per session where `hits.page.pagePath = "/application-complete/"` is true.  You are taking the min of the timestamp in your inner query, but not your outer query.

If it were me, I would structure my query like this:

```
-- Get all relevant GA Data
with ga as (
  select
    CONCAT(CAST(visitId AS STRING),'_',fullVisitorId) AS sessionId,
    channelGrouping,
    hits.time as hit_ts,
    hits.page.pagePath
  from `project.dataset.ga_sessions_20190923`
  left join unnest(hits) AS hits
  where hits.type = 'PAGE' and hits.page.pagePath in ('/get-a-quote/','/application-complete/') and hits.time > 0
),
-- Get first instance of quote
first_quote as (
  select
    sessionId,
    channelGrouping,
    min(hit_ts) as quote_ts
  from ga
  where pagePath = '/get-a-quote/'
  group by 1,2
),
-- Get first instance of app-complete
first_app_complete as (
  select
    sessionId,
    channelGrouping,
    min(hit_ts) as app_complete_ts
  from ga
  where pagePath = '/application-complete/'
  group by 1,2
),
-- Join it all together and calc differences
joined as (
  select
    sessionID,
    channelGrouping,
    timestamp_diff(app_complete_ts, quote_ts, second) as ts_diff_seconds
  from first_quote
  inner join first_app_complete using(sessionID,channelGrouping)
)
select * from joined
-- select channelGrouping, count(sessionID) as session_count, avg(ts_diff_seconds) as average_seconds_to_complete from joined group by 1
```

Comment: That is definitely a much better way to structure the query, and it works - thanks so much